# Where are databases stored in the rails server?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, macos

I'm having a lot of run with Ruby, creating some basic web apps. When looking at the logs of the rails server in terminal, I see mysql queries.

```
Refinery::User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "refinery_users".* FROM "refinery_users" WHERE "refinery_users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
```

Theses are relating to databases that I've created, but where do these databases exist? In the rails server? Where is the rails server stored in OSX? **Can I browse what's inside, specifically, the databases?**

Thanks, I know this doesn't have much practical use, but I want to understand the **concepts** behind what's going on, rather than just having superficial knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Rails uses SQLite3. The database files are stored in the /db directory in the root of your app. There should be a file called development.sqlite3.

To access that database, open a terminal session, go to the root directory of your app and enter `sqlite3 db/development.sqlite3`. More info on the sqlite shell here: http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html

Rather than messing around in the SQLite shell, I think you'd be better off 1) looking at /db/schema.rb to see the structure of your database and 2) using `rails console` to look at the data.

If you want to know, for any given Rails app, what database it's using, look at /config/database.yml. That gives you the adapter, name of the database, location, etc.

Also, SQLite is generally just for kicking off development. I wouldn't recommend using it when your schema starts getting more complex. Personally, I never use it. I immediately set up a mySQL database for any new Rails projects.

Comment: Excellent! I also want the finest wines available to humanity. And we want them here, and we want them now.